# Time based event queue

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I have windows form application, where user can add a specific time to list(List timeQueue) and i would like to pop a messagebox to user at a time from list.

Something like this:

- List contains Datetimes - 01:00:00, 02:00:00, 14:00:00 etc.
- Current time is 00:00:00, after 1 hour a messagebox pops to user informing him its 01:00:00
- after 1 more hour another one.

However at 12:00:00 user adds time 13:00:00 to queue, which is before 14:00:00, so it should pop before it, even though it was added after.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [sorted list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a Timer!

Comment: Maybe it's a little over exaggerated, but have a look at [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net). If there is more involved than just to popup a message box, this might be a valuable tool.